# Nested filtering in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot application with MySQL db, where I have several related entities: Listing, Lesson, Classroom, and others. I want to implement a filter endpoint for the Listing entity that allows me to filter results based on various criteria like classroomType, groupLimit, priceFrom, priceTo, languageId, categoryId, lessonStart, lessonEnd, page, and pageLimit. Also a "searchQuery" criteria, which would filter Listings by matching Listing.keywords list. How can I implement such a comprehensive filtering endpoint in Spring Boot?

Additionally, I'm curious if there are any libraries available that could streamline the process of building and managing this kind of filtering functionality.

Thank you in advance for any insights or guidance!

Here is structure of my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "listing")
@Data
public class Listing {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 2000)
    private String description;

    @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 2000)
    private List<String> keywords;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "listing_id")
    private List<Lesson> lessons;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lesson")
@Data
public class Lesson {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id", nullable = false)
    private Language language;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id", nullable = false)
    private Classroom classroom;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double price;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classroom")
@Data
public class Classroom {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "group_limit", nullable = false)
    private int groupLimit;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private ClassroomType type;

}
```

```
public class Language {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String code;
}
```

```
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
}
```

```
@Converter
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {
    private static final String SPLIT_CHAR = ";";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> stringList) {
        return stringList != null ? String.join(SPLIT_CHAR, stringList) : "";
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String string) {
        return string != null ? Arrays.asList(string.split(SPLIT_CHAR)) : emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would use a "StringListConverter" while JPA 1.0 already support collection type attribute, especially `List<String>`, and allow ... querying on a collection ? see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections